# .net core mvc: adding controller with crud functionality on area didn't generate code and link correctly

Tags: view, controller, crud, area

I have create an whole starting website with crud functionality and it work.

But when i do the same using Areas folders, its not working.

When i do the auto generator code with scaffolder wizard(add->controller), all the page(Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Index) and controller are generated correctly in the good areas folder.

I can access all the page, but all the links and header are not generated like my first project.

Its look that the wizard didn't know Areas folder structure to correctly create Header and Links in each pages.

Somebody have an idea?

Comment: You can describe your problem and the way you added the scaffolding in detail, because for me, it works very well.

Comment: @Yinqiu:  its look that part of the problem can be to move _ViewImport.cshtml and _ViewStart.cshtml from MVC Views folder to application root(to let Areas folder access Views\_Layout.cshtml file).  But for now i finally do what i do often in programming:  completely restart apps from scratch(empty MVC projects) and minimize at max uses of Wizard.  I think this way is better to understand all based global mechanism.

i can add that i have some error in my routing too(for controller).

Comment: @Yinqiu: To answer your question, i have reproduce the exact tree of the application root to subfolder Manage in Areas folder(Controllers, Views, etc.) and right-click on Controllers folder, Add, MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework, configure Model and Context.

Problem:  Not any link created, like:  Create, edit, Delete for row and just label for 'Create New'.  I have to write /create in the URL; but just got textbox without label.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Models folder needs to be in the same typical MVC folder structure, even in Areas.